# Apply a function to a subset of data.table columns, by column-indices instead of name

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns, indices

I'm trying to apply a function to a group of columns in a large data.table without referring to each one individually.

```
a <- data.table(
  a=as.character(rnorm(5)),
  b=as.character(rnorm(5)),
  c=as.character(rnorm(5)),
  d=as.character(rnorm(5))
)
b <- c('a','b','c','d')
```

with the MWE above, this:

```
a[,b=as.numeric(b),with=F]
```

works, but this:

```
a[,b[2:3]:=data.table(as.numeric(b[2:3])),with=F]
```

doesn't work. What is the correct way to apply the `as.numeric` function to just columns 2 and 3 of `a` without referring to them individually.

(In the actual data set there are tens of columns so it would be impractical)

Comment: Also, if you just want to reference multiple columns by indices, `,with=F]` allows j to be column-indices e.g. `dt[, 2:3, with =F`. But applying a function to each is more complicated, as per @mnel's answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The idiomatic approach is to use `.SD` and `.SDcols`

You can force the RHS to be evaluated in the parent frame by wrapping in `()`

```
a[, (b) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = b]
```

For columns 2:3

```
a[, 2:3 := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = 2:3]
```

or

```
mysubset <- 2:3
a[, (mysubset) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = mysubset]
```

Comment: If you want to use the "by" grouping here, does that have to be included in advance, in `mysubset`?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander - No, the By columns are not in `.SD`, they exist as single values in the environment in which `.SD` is created.

Comment: Hi how do i use this if I want to apply the function on all columns but 'b'? Thanks!

Comment: @Christa You could still use `a[, (b[b != 'b']) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = b[b != 'b']]` then. But `mySubset <- setdiff(b, 'b')` followed by `a[, (mySubset) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = mySubset]` is more readable and seems straight-forward