# How to indicate row.names=1 using fread() in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to consider the first column in my *.csv* file as a sequence of *rownames*. Usually I used to do the following:

```
read.csv("example_file.csv", row.names=1)
```

But I want to do this with the `fread()` function in the `data.table` R package, as it runs very quickly.

Comment: Don't use rownames with data.table. Just have them as a column.

Comment: If you want to convert to a `data.frame` after `fread`, just use `data.frame(fread("example_file.csv"), row.names=1)`. But I suggest working with `data.table` instead.

Comment: But my remaining columns are numeric, and i want to apply some functions on them. I want these to be rownames only and intend to work with data.table not data.frame that's what the problem is

Comment: @koundy To do that see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16783769/403310

Comment: @MattDowle I think there is some validity here, if one wanted to use the resulting object as a matrix, rather than a data.frame/data.table. I am working with some data that I want to apply matrix math to, and would prefer to use fread for speed purposes. Currently I am using `data.matrix(read.csv("myfile.csv", row.names = 1))`.

Comment: @dayne Is [`bigmemory::read.big.matrix`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigmemory/functions/write.big.matrix) faster than `read.csv` and fast enough?  If not please file a feature request on the github tracker - thanks.

Comment: Check out `mstrsplit` from the "iotools" package for another fast option. Not sure how it compares with `fread`....

Answer (score 5):

```
X <- as.matrix(fread("bigmatrix.csv"),rownames=1)
```

Comment: x <- data.frame(fread("example_file.csv"), row.names=1) #if you need a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Why not saving the *rownames* in a column:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000))
df$row_name = row.names(df)   
fwrite(df,file="example_file.csv")
```

Then you can load the saved CSV.

```
df <- fread(file="example_file.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

From a small search I've done, [data.tables never uses row names. Since data.tables inherit from data.frames, it still has the row names attribute. But it never uses them](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html).

However, you can probably use [this answer (similar post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184181/reading-file-using-fread-with-row-and-column-names) and later make the rowname column into your actual rownames. Though, it might not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just one function, convert to a dataframe

```
a <- fread(file="example_file.csv")  %>% as.data.frame()
row.names(a) <- a$V1
```